# STL "erase-remove" idiom: Why not "resize-remove"?

Tags: c++, stl, erase-remove-idiom

It is commonly understood that a good way to fully delete desired items from a `std::vector` is the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

As noted in the above link (as of the date of this posting), in code the **erase-remove** idiom looks like this:

```
int main()
{
  // initialises a vector that holds the numbers from 0-9.
  std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

  // erase-remove idiom to completely eliminate the desired items from the vector
  v.erase( std::remove( std::begin(v), std::end(v), 5 ), std::end(v) ); 
}
```

I would like to know whether a `resize-remove` idiom is equivalent in terms of functionality and performance to the `erase-remove` idiom.  Or, perhaps I am missing something obvious?

Is the following `resize-remove` idiom equivalent to the above `erase-remove` idiom?

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

  // Is this "resize-remove" approach equivalent to the "erase-remove" idiom?
  v.resize( std::remove( std::begin(v), std::end(v), 5 ) - v.begin() ); 
}
```

Comment: "resize-remove" is - by definition - not an "idiom" as the phrase is not in use by others...

Comment: @TonyD Which is, by itself, a very strong reason for preferring the erase-remove idiom.

Comment: The (rhetorical) question I'd like to add is: why on earth does the STL not take care of this chore on its own by default, so that it couldn't have become an idiom in the first place...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my opinion, there are two reasons:

1. `std::remove` algorithm requires only Forward Iterator, but `-` op requires Random Access Iterator.
2. The result of `std::remove` means "the new end of container". Logically, we should erase [ "the new end of container" , "the old end of container" ).

Comment: The first is a very good point (although it doesn't affect `std::vector`).

Answer (score 6):

It is equivalent for std::vector, but not for std::list or other containers. Not sure if subtracting iterators is even possible for std::list, and even if it is, it is a O(N) operation.

Comment: It's not possible. You'd have to use `std::distance`, which is O(N).

Comment: Then again, it's O(N) in the elements to remove, plus it will bring those elements into cache. So practically it's not horrible.

Comment: @MSalters: It is the other way around. It is O(N) in the elements NOT to remove. The overall complexity of the idiom will not change, because `std::remove()` already is O(N), but in practice constants matter too.

Comment: @greenlantern: You'd iterate backwards from end(), if only because of the cache issue.

Comment: @MSalters: You mean changing the code to `v.resize(v.size() - std::distance(std::remove(...), v.end()))`? Yes, that would be a little less horrible :-)

Comment: @greenlantern: That was pretty much a given since `operator-` isn't defined on `list::iterator`.

Comment: @MSalters: You could use the original code and just change `operator-` to `std::distance`: `v.resize(std::distance(v.begin(), std::remove(...)));`. Btw. notice how the erase-remove idiom and the code in my previous comment both contain the `std::remove(...), v.end()` part, but with erase-remove the rest is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't make any difference; `resize` is defined in terms
of `insert` and `erase`. But it is usually preferable to use the
standard idiom, so that it can easily be recognized.  And of
course, the erase-remove idiom will work with any sequence
container, and not just those which support `resize`.  (All of
the standard containers do seem to support `resize`, but it
doesn't seem to be a requirement.  So it might not be available
on user defined containers, even though they support all
required operations.)

In terms of performance: the `resize` must do one additional
test, to determine whether it is erasing or inserting, but
I can't imagine this making a significant impact.

Comment: `resize` on a `std::list` has the additional drawback that it has to find the new end of the list, by iterating O(n), while that exact end iterator returned by `remove` has been thrown away after calculating `X-begin(), which is again O(n).

Comment: @ArneMertz: `std::list` is bidirectional (double linked). It's pretty cheap to find the new end: you just pop the current end until the size is right. The new end is the predecessor of the last popped element.

Comment: @ArneMertz I was wondering about that.  I didn't expect to even find it, because it can't be implemented efficiently.  (And of course, you can't do the different of the iterators directly if they aren't random access either.)

Comment: @MSalters You're right, but then why does the standard describe it in terms of `advance` and `erase`?  (Does `erase` guarantee the order in which the destructors are called?  I don't think so, but if so, your implementation wouldn't call them in the correct order.)

Comment: Your answer and @ikh's are both enlightening - I wish they could be combined, as they make some different points.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum And TonyD also made an important point in his comment.  Nothing surprising: different people think in different ways, and the most complete answer to any non-trivial question will probably involve answers by several different people.

Answer (score 1):

I think `erase` in `erase(first,last)` guarantees that no elements before `first` are accessed or modified, while `resize` only guarantees this when no reallocation happens because of the resize.

Edit: as pointed out by others, such a reallocation will never happen, so there's no difference

Comment: It's guaranteed that resizing to a smaller size does not reallocate.

Comment: More explicitly: `resize` is defined in terms of `erase` and `insert`.  So when it erases, it has the same guarantees as `erase`.